# Customizing the SharePoint CRM List Part

Tags: development, dynamics-crm

is it possible to customize the CRM Listpart that is delivered by Microsoft. I would like to add a dropdown listbox to the presentation in CRM based on the documenttype in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This webpart (if you are talking about the one for 4.0) is not supported from Microsoft anymore, and is only provided as-is.

The more common way to list data from Dynamics CRM in SharePoint would be to use BCS

[Here is a video and some helpful links from MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/06/16/teched-na-2011-session-recording-crm-and-sharepoint.aspx) that will get you started with than in an instance!

Also [this](http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/integrating-dynamics-crm-data-into-sharepoint-2010/) is a great resource about the matter.